# Take C# const from backend and use it in JS file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, c#-3.0

I have one tricky question.

Is there a way to take C# const and use it in .JS script with Jquery ?

This is how const look:

```
 public class UserRoles
 {
    public const string Read = "Read";
    public const string ReadWrite = "ReadWrite";
 }
```

Comment: Not directly. You would need to output the `const` value to the HTML and then read that in your JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends a bit of what you are trying to do with those values.

You could place the values in a js object when your UI initializes (ex: window.YourAppName.Constants.Read = "your C# constant" in Index.html). Then you could load your jquery script and make use of the constant values once the document finished loading.

Alternatively, if you are using MVC, you can make use of  tags within your views, and thus have access to C# code (viewmodel, enums, etc.). However, if you have lots of js code then it would be best to keep that in js files and in such a case I would go for the first option.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Razor in JavaScript files, you would have to have the variable passed to a razor view in the viewbag/data or model.

Then in the shared layout you could create a javascript function that returns this variable, then in your .JS file you could call that function to get the variable as long as it is loaded after.